# Import Revolution HTML slider to wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, revolution-slider

I have a slider HTML created. I want to import that to wordprss revolution plugin slider. How can that be possible. There is no way of importing html to convert to slides.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I actually just have revolution slider html like  https://i.imgur.com/Rdi73ZE.png

Comment: any help is really appreciated